# Is changing JS code by user is bad thing?

Tags: javascript, client-side, developer-tools

I'm building a recent portal based on Drupal 8.6 as API and Vue.js as SPA.I do for now tones of research about OAuth authentication security etc, but i can't stop thinking about user changing code by Developer Tools.

I not worried about data leak, because this should be secured on a backed as well, but what if user change isLogin() to always true and see for example logged user HTML template.

Is there some steps I should take and this is real problem or this problem is big only in my head, and this is way that it works ?

Thanks!

Comment: No, and there's little you can do to prevent it. If it reaches the client, the client can see and change it.

Comment: I don't see the issue when it comes to OAuth, as far as I know to get a token you need to have access to the web server which would require you to have a back end and so you can do your authentication there.

Comment: Is there any sensitive information in the "*logged-in user HTML template*"? If yes, the template should not be served until the server authenticated the user, if no, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Just follow the main principle of web security: never trust the client. The private data should only be sent to the client when it provides a way to authenticate to the server. That way even if the clientside code gets changed, no data gets exposed as the server wouldn't send private data.